# Angular: How to dynamically go back?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router, angular-routerlink

I help with something.

I have 3 components, A, B, C.

My application starts on component 'A'.
The user is able to get into component 'B' from multiple routes/components.
Component 'B' has a link to component 'C'.

Here is the the problem... I want component 'B' to always go to the previous page. `location.back()` doesn't work because the if the clicks to go to component 'C' from component 'B', the `back()` will take the user back to 'C', since it uses the js `history.back`

I know it's a bit confusing, but does it make sense? In other words, when the user is in component 'B' and clicks on the BACK button, the user will always go to the previous route independently if component 'C' got activated.

Thanks

---

## Update

I got a little flow
[image: Untitled-Diagram.png]

Comment: can you show the routes for these components?

Comment: Reading this I feel like the actual behavior and the desired one exactly the same while it is still not what you want %). maybe you can rephrase? or maybe add a small drawing

Comment: wouldn't it work as long as the only way to go from C to B is using location.back();? Can you not chain the backs together to go from C to B to A?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your routes are:

```
const routes = [
    { path: 'a', component: AComponent },
    { path: 'b', component: BComponent },
    { path: 'c', component: CComponent }
];
```

Then the "go back" link in B and C components is as simple as:

```
<!-- b.component.html -->
<a [routerLink]="['/a']">Back</a>

<!-- c.component.html -->
<a [routerLink]="['/b']">Back</a>
```

Note: Both B and C components must have `RouterModule` in the `imports` section of the module which declares them.

Comment: Hey @funkizer thanks, but there is just one I thing I a just realized I've omitted. The component B can be access from component A and component Z. If the user came from component A, they should go back to A, if he came from Z, go back to Z. Make sense? Thank you

Comment: Ok then you can use queryParams to keep the state. Eg. in Z: `<a [routerLink]="['/b']" [queryParams]="{ return: '/z' }">B</a>` . In component B check this.route (`ActivatedRoute`) .queryParams.return